# Is there a way to create a lazy custom property with NHibernate?

Tags: nhibernate, lazy-loading

I have a custom property (to binding in a Grid) like that :

```
public class MyClass
{ 
       public virtual IList<clsClass2> MyList{ get; set; }  //Lazy loaded
       public virtual string CustomProperty //To use on Grid Binding
       {
          get
          {
             if (!MyList.IsNullOrEmpty())
                return MyList.Select(__comp => __comp.Name).ToList().ToString(", ");
                return string.Empty;
          }
       }   
}
```

Its working fine... But that way everytime I load a MyClass object, its load every MyList element because of the CustomProperty...

Is there a better way to do that?

Thanks

Comment: lazyloaded property whith formula

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 public virtual string CustomProperty //To use on Grid Binding
 {
    get; private set;
 }

// using FLuentMapping
Map(x => x.CustomProperty).Formula("(SELECT ... FROM Class2Table c2 WHERE c2.MyClass_id = Id)");
```

and exchange `...` with your database syntax of aggregating the string [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/194852/671619)

Comment: Tried using XML PATH, but got an error... I found that : https://nhibernate.jira.com/browse/NH-2132 ... So I think I cannot use XML PATH on NHibernate Formula.... Is there any other way?